# Is the illustrator of Shokugeki no Soma a hentai mangaka?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma, shun-saeki

Whenever I saw some good art or illustration I usually try to find the artist, and when I search for "Shun Saeki" ([He is Shokugeki no Soma illustrator](http://shokugekinosoma.wikia.com/wiki/Shun_Saeki)) I came across this topic on MAL. [Shun Saeki, the illustrator of this series is a H mangaka.](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1397908)

Is this true that Shokugeki no Soma artist is a hentai mangaka? Looking how the foodgasm is drawn I wouldn't be surprised if this is true.

[NSFW Foodgasm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9SFlm.jpg)

Comment: For a broader piece on this:  TVTropes explores ["bleached underpants"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BleachedUnderpants) and does have a list of mangaka that have either started with hentai or have done hentai during their career.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googled "Shun Saeki" wouldn't get any satisfying result, so I tried "Saeki Shun" and found out that he really is a hentai artist under the name Tosh on circle Hikakuteki Simple na Panty.

This is one of his other manga titled Yuukai Trouble

[image]

[Almost all of his work have explicit content](http://myanimelist.net/people/11085/Shun_Saeki)